# Implement method for class in a different class

Tags: java, interface, lambda

There is a class A which has an undefined method called OnEvent. I want this method to be define by the class that instantiates a class A Object.

Like this:

```
public class A{
    int someVar=1;
    float anotherVar=2;

    public void method1(){ 
        ...

        if( event )
            OnEvent();
        ...
    }

    //OnEvent is not defined!!
    OnEvent();
}
```

And another class, in a different package:

```
public class B{
    A objA = new A();

    public void method1(){ 
        //I need to do something like
        objA.setOnEvent( this.OnEvent() );
       }

    OnEvent(){
        //Do something
    }

}
```

I've looked this up and Interfaces and/or lambda expressions are the way to implements this, but I have been unable to do it successfully. Could you please provide some pointers on how to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make the `A` class `abstract` (and the `OnClick()` method `abstract`, too)`.

Then, you can create anonymous instance(s) of `A`, with directly providing an implementation for `OnClick()`.

For example:

```
public abstract class A{
    ...

    public abstract void OnEvent();
}

public class B{
    A objA = new A() {
        public void OnClick() {
            //OnClick implementation
        }
    };
    ...
}
```

Comment: Does Java 8 allow a class to have an `abstract` method without also being labelled `abstract`?

Comment: @AmiguelS, as an anonymous implementation. Just like the example I've shown.

Comment: This is a very insightful answer and I have upvoted it.

Answer (score 2):

That's not directly possible. But you can *delegate* the method:

```
public interface OnEvent {
    public void onEvent();
}

public class A {
    OnEvent delegate;

    public void onEvent() {
        delegate.onEvent();
    }

    public void setOnEvent(OnEvent delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }
}

public class B implements OnEvent {
    public void onEvent() {
    }
}
```

See the [*delegation pattern*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern)

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it (with an interface) :

```
public interface OnEventInterface {
    public void OnEvent ();
}

public class B implements OnEventInterface {
    A objA = new A();

    public void method1(){ 
        //I need to do something like
        objA.setOnEvent( this );
       }

    OnEvent(){
        //Do something
    }

}
```

Then in A :

```
public class A{
    int someVar=1;
    float anotherVar=2;
    private onEventInterface;

    public void method1(){ 
        ...

        if( event )
            onEventInterface.OnEvent();
        ...
    }

    public void setOnEvent (OnEventInterface handler) {
        onEventInterface = handler;
    }
}
```